# Enumerate Dictionary.Values vs Dictionary itself

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, asp.net-core, .net-core

I was exploring the sources of ASP.NET core on GitHub to see what kind of tricks the ASP.NET team used to speed up the framework. I saw something that intrigued me. In the source code of the [ServiceProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/ServiceProvider.cs), in the Dispose implementation, they enumerate a dictionary, and they put a comment to indicate a performance trick :

```
private readonly Dictionary<IService, object> _resolvedServices = new Dictionary<IService, object>();

// Code removed for brevity

public void Dispose()    
{        
    // Code removed for brevity

    // PERF: We've enumerating the dictionary so that we don't allocate to enumerate.
    // .Values allocates a KeyCollection on the heap, enumerating the dictionary allocates
    // a struct enumerator
    foreach (var entry in _resolvedServices)
    {
        (entry.Value as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
    }

    _resolvedServices.Clear();        
}
```

What is the difference if the dictionary is enumerated like that ?

```
foreach (var entry in _resolvedServices.Values)
{
    (entry as IDisposable)?.Dispose();
}
```

It has a performance impact ? Or it's because allocate a [ValueCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8bctb9c(v=vs.110).aspx) will consume more memory ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're right, this is about memory consumption. The difference is actually pretty well described in the comment: accessing the `Value` property of a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` [will allocate a `ValueCollection`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,165), which is a class (reference type), on the heap.

`foreach`'ing through the dictionary itself results in a call to [`GetEnumerator()`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,272) which returns an [`Enumerator`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs,696). This is a `struct` and will be allocated on the stack rather than on the heap.

Comment: It seems I missed the concept of Heaping and Stacking that is well described here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx
Thanks by the way.